# ORA-12839: COMMIT followed by MERGE /*+PARALLEL*/. still an issue

Tags: sql, oracle

I am altering session to use Parallel DML using

```
ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML;
```

Then performs MERGE statement with PARALLEL

```
MERGE /*+PARALLEL*/ INTO
COMMIT;
```

Then another MERGE without PARALLEL

I get ORA-12839: cannot modify an object in parallel after modifying it.

I cannot share the real log as it is customer log. I tried to reproduce the scenario but not able to reproduce.

Is there something getting set somewhere which needs to disabled? Not able to understand what is going wrong here?

Just to update: Parallel degree is set by customer and on unsetting degree it started working.

Comment: Found this... "ORA-12839: cannot modify an object in parallel after modifying it
Cause: Within the same transaction, an attempt was made to perform parallel modification operations on a table after it had been modified. This is not permitted."  Can you commit between the first and second MERGE statements?

Comment: I have already done this... It is not reproducible on my environment. But It got reproduced on customer environment once. The same code. I am doing COMMIT between two MERGEs

Comment: Can someone help me on this?

Comment: I've not experienced the problem before.  But, Googling more on it, it appears you cannot update a table a second time after a parallel DML without committing the first update.  This was specified above.  Unless you provide more information about your script/logs, there is not much else we can do.